# entity model removed by mistake how to reconfigure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, windowsformsintegration

my friend remove entity model from my working project of c# visual studio ,

in most of forms i am using core ADO.net but for datagridviews i was using 
entityframework

now its not working i tried to reconfigure it but its not working showing error

> "could not load projectnameentities from assembly"

please help me what should i do?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace shopBillingSystem
{

static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Main());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined projectnameentities in a separate assembly ?

Comment: no that  is same "shopBillingSystementities"

Comment: even i dont want to use entityframwork  actually i want to update config file but not know what to do

Comment: did he totally removed edmx file

Comment: i think i found solution ... i added new entitymodel from database and rename in bsl/config file and also rename in main config file

Answer (score 1):

i think i found solution ... i added new entitymodel from database and rename in bsl/config file and also rename in main config file and now it works fine...